# Kotlin flows collected only once in repeatOnLifecycle()

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to collect weather data from flows after each update. It works on initializing the UI state in ViewModel with empty object and on receiving the first piece of data, but then, while the state still gets updates, nothing is being collected. So the log will always look like:

```
New item! List is []
Updated uiState with city1
New item! List is [WeatherData ...] (of city1)
Updated uiState with city2
Updated uiState with city3
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for log to look like this:

```
New item! List is []
Updated uiState with city1
New item! List is [WeatherData ...] (of city1)
Updated uiState with city2
New item! List is [WeatherData ...] (of city1 and city2)
Updated uiState with city3
New item! List is [WeatherData ...] (of city1, city2 and city3)
```

#### MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // <...>
    val weatherViewModel: WeatherViewModel by viewModels()
    buttonAddCity.setOnClickListener {
        weatherViewModel.addCity(city)
    }
    
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            weatherViewModel.uiState.collect { data ->
                Log.d("MY_TAG", "New item! List is ${data.weatherList}!")
                // <...>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### WeatherViewModel.kt

```kotlin
class WeatherViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val repository = WeatherRepository(Dispatchers.IO)
    private var _uiState = MutableStateFlow(WeatherUIState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<WeatherUIState> = _uiState

    fun fetchWeather(city: String) {
        Log.d("MY_TAG", "Updated uiState with $city")
        _uiState.update { it.copy(weatherList = repository.weather) }
    }

    fun addCity(city: String) {
        val cityTrim = city.filter { !it.isWhitespace() }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // Checks if the city is already present and fetches weather into           
            // repository.weather: ArrayList<WeatherData> variable

            if (repository.addCity(cityTrim)) {
                fetchWeather(cityTrim)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### WeatherUIState.kt

```kotlin
data class WeatherUIState (
    val weatherList: ArrayList<WeatherData> = arrayListOf()
)
```

I've tried rewriting the fetchWeather function with direct value assignment, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Does `repository.weather` actually change between calls? If not, the behavior you're seeing is expected. A `StateFlow` won't emit the same state multiple times.

Comment: Also be careful you're not just mutating `repository.weather` by adding new cities to it - when you do `it.copy(weatherList = repository.weather)` you're creating a new data class instance but with a reference to *the same list object*. So if that list gets updated, the current value in the `StateFlow` will reflect that change too - and when you create a new value and it gets compared to the current one, they'll be identical since they just contain the same list object (and like *gpunto* says, `StateFlow` acts like `distinctUntilChanged` and only emits if the new value is *not equal*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@cactustictacs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13598222/cactustictacs), I managed to find an error: the object in the uiState always stored the *same* reference to the list and changes in it weren't detected by the StateFlow. So the decision here is to change the reference every time the list in repository is updated (meaning, to copy it).

#### WeatherRepository.kt

```kotlin
fun getWeatherAll(): ArrayList<WeatherData> {
        val weatherNew = arrayListOf<WeatherData>()
        weatherNew.addAll(weather)
        return weatherNew
    }
```

#### WeatherViewModel.kt

```kotlin
fun fetchWeather(city: String) {
     // _uiState.update { it.copy(weatherList = repository.weather) }
        _uiState.update { it.copy(weatherList = repository.getWeatherAll()) }
        Log.d("MY_TAG", "Updated uiState with $city")
    }
```